# Python openCV VideoCapture() returns false. But worked initially

Tags: python, opencv, path, frames

I am writing a basic program to read video frame from a video file and display it on screen using OpenCV functions. I was able to do that. But when I ran the same file after few days, I was unable to capture the frames using VideoCapture Function in OpenCV.

But reading frames from webcam still works. But I am unable to read frames from a video file

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video1.mp4') 

# print(cap.isOpened())  Just for debugging purpose, it prints false

while cap.isOpened():
    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    cv2.imshow('Title', frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF==ord('q'):# or frame_count > 25:
        break 
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above snippet is the one I wrote. What might be the possible reason for it to work properly initially, but now failing to do so?

Comment: it's always relative paths and CWD... `assert os.path.exists("video1.mp4")` what does that say?

Comment: I believe your error would be relative to the path of your video file. Look for a way to specify in what folder exactly the program will look for the MP4 file. So, for example, instead of writing 'video1.mp4' you'd write 'folderName/video1.mp4'

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks a lot both of you. It worked when I used my complete path. But isn't it subtle? Why is it so? that it worked for me initially and later stopped working? Can anyone explain me why is it mandatory to use complete path/ relative path?

Comment: @FlyingFish (unable to tag in a single comment)

Comment: it is _not_ mandatory to use absolute paths. relative paths work just fine, if you know the "current working directory" that your script is executed in. the CWD is unrelated to the directory *containing* the script file.